# How to write Regular expressions in asp.net? for Email Validator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know the General formula for Writing Regular Expression? Any article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a general formula.  Regex is a non-trivial language for matching strings.  There are plenty of books and tutorials available.

One of the better ways of learning regex is to use a piece of regex designer software, [like this one](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/).

Regexes for emails are tricky, but there are some good ones here: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Regexes for email addresses are trickier than you'd think. Here's a good page to start: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

A "complete" regex here: http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, start with the Regex class.  And read lots of tutorials, like [this one](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

in .vb if you dont care about a postback....

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

valueStr = Regex.Replace(oldString, ",", ",@")

Another common way to do it is in javascript in your aspx page without a postback.

script type = "text/javascript"

```
function intChecker(field) {

    //use regular expressions to take out alphanumeric characters
    //and special characters such as !@#$ 
    //The reason I run the match before I run the replace is so that the
    //cursor doesn't jump to the end of the textbox unless it is a bad character
    var regExp2 = /[A-Za-z\.\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\,\?\:\;\_\-\+\=\~\/]/g;
    if (field.value.match(regExp2)) {
        field.value = field.value.replace(regExp2, '');
    }

}
```

/script

This will get you started with regex in vb.
You will need to find the expression to validate the email address.
Have fun!